# Getting Identity provider login error when trying to authenticate user from Microsoft via keycloak

Tags: reactjs, django, keycloak

I am trying to authenticate the user from Microsoft-AD IDP using keycloak as an identity broker.

Technology stack used:

- Frontend: React
- Backend: Django (python)
- IAM solution: Keycloak
- IDP: Microsoft

I am redirecting the backend views to keycloak's authorization endpoint for getting code as per oauth2:

...

```
    def login(self, request):
        authorization_endpoint="http://keycloakIP:port/auth/realms/r1/protocol/openid-connect/auth"
        redirect_uri="http://localhost:8000/login/getAccessToken"   *#django API url to get access token after getting authorization code* 
        auth_request=authorization_endpoint+'?client_id='+client_id_var+'&response_type=code&scope=openid&redirect_uri='+redirect_uri
        return redirect(auth_request)
```

...

When this login API is hit from frontend then it starts giving 400 bad request error at this **redirect(auth_request)**  and **type=IDENTITY_PROVIDER_LOGIN_ERROR, realmId=r1, clientId=null, userId=null, ipAddress=IP, error=invalid_code, identity_provider=M-AD** error at keycloak logs.

But when this login API is hit from the browser directly passing required query params like usernmae.... it works completely fine and redirects to the keycloak (which in turn redirect to Microsoft) and gets back the access token after succesful authentication...

Questions:

1.whether issue is with the redirect urls put in the API or some keycloak config... bcoz its working in one way but not the other.

2.why is **clientId=null** shown in keycloak logs bcoz... its picking the correct realmId, IPAddress but not clientId..

Comment: Having the same issue here. Did you find a way to solve this?